# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Marionette.LayoutView.extend')

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Learning Marionette and trying to create regions using the Marionette LayoutView. And I got the error message as described in the question title. Went over the codes many times but just could not see where the problem is. Hopefully someone can tell me. Thanks. Apparently the problem line is Marionette.LayoutView is undefined, and I don't know why:

> var AppLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend(

```
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette'),
    Controller = require('./controller'),
    Router = require('./router'),
    UserModel = require('./models/user'),
    UsersCollection = require('./collections/users');    

module.exports = App = function App() {};

    App.prototype.start = function(){
        App.core = new Marionette.Application();

        App.core.on("initialize:before", function (options) {
            //App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'App: Initializing');

            App.views = {};
            App.data = {};

            //define the App regions
            var AppLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({ 
                template: "#app-container",

                regions: {
                  headerRegion: "#header-region",
                  mainRegion: "#main-region",
                  drawerRegion: "#drawer-region",   
                  dialog: "#dialog-region"      
                }
            });

            App.mainlayout = new AppLayoutView();
            App.mainlayout.render();

            var DashLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({ 
              template: "#dashboard-template",

              regions: {
                dashHeaderRegion: "#dbheader-region",
                dashMainRegion: "#dbmain-region",
              }
            });

            App.dashlayout = new DashLayoutView();
            App.dashlayout.render();

            // load up some initial data:
            var users = new UsersCollection();
            users.fetch({
                success: function() {
                    App.data.users = users;
                    App.core.vent.trigger('app:start');
                }
            });
        });

        App.core.vent.bind('app:start', function(options){
            //App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'App: Starting');
            if (Backbone.history) {
                App.controller = new Controller();
                App.router = new Router({ controller: App.controller });
                //App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'App: Backbone.history starting');
                Backbone.history.start();
            }

            //new up and views and render for base app here...
            //App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'App: Done starting and running!');
        });

        App.core.vent.bind('app:log', function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });

        App.core.start();
    };
```

Comment: The code you posted as it is, has syntax error `var AppLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend( var Marionette`. You can't declare variables in a function invokation. please [edit] and update the question

Comment: Marionette is not stand-alone, it requires Backbone which again requires jquery/zepto and underscore so you need to require those as well.

Comment: @ivarni I am aware of the dependencies for Marionette. This was taken of by Browserify using shim, which is not shown in the codes.

Comment: @TJ I was building using some sample codes. And definitely lacking in understanding when I attempt to expand with my own codes. Anyhow I refactored these codes starting from scratch and managed to resolve the error issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit that the question I posted was ambiguous. My apologies. Part of my learning process. Anyhow for the record, I have refactored my codes as below that is now working for me.

```
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette'),
    Controller = require('./controller'),
    Router = require('./router');


App = new Marionette.Application();

App.on("before:start", function(){

    App.addRegions({
        headerRegion: "#header-region",
        mainHeaderRegion: "#content-header",    
        mainRegion: "#main-region",
        drawerRegion: "#drawer-region",
        dialog: "#dialog-region"
    });

});


App.on("start", function(){

    if (Backbone.history) {
        App.controller = new Controller();
        App.router= new Router({ controller: App.controller });

        //App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'App: Backbone.history starting');
        Backbone.history.start();
    }

});

App.vent.bind('app:log', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});

App.start();
```